# Getting substring for all items in a column daframe with a given delimeter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with strings in a column.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['asa asas s','qw wewe de','ewew ewe ww']})
```

I need to split this string to 2 from the first space character. So the resultant data frame should have 2 additional columns.

```
Col1            Part1       Part2
asa asas s      asa         asas s
qw wewe de      qw          wewe de
ewew ewe ww     ewew        ewe ww
```

I tried to get the index and use python substring as follows:

```
df['ColIdx']=df.Col1.str.find(' ')
df['Part1']=df.Col1[:df.CityIdx]
df['Part2']=df.Col1[df.CityIdx:]
```

Unfortunately I am getting "cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers" on the Part1 line. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `df[['part1','part2']] = df.Col1.str.split(' ',1, expand=True)`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny This is the most elegant and simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `split`

```
df = df.join(df.Col1.str.split(' ', 1, expand=True))|
```

Update check the name

```
df[['part1','part2']] = df.Col1.str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Comment: Your solution is good but lacks the column names. Could you update it according to Micheal's suggestion so we can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `str.replace` here:

```
df['Part1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace('^(\w+)\b.*$', '\\1')
df['Part2'] = df['Col1'].str.replace('^\w+\s*', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get part1 by splitting on the " " using the .str method to use the string properties on the series and then returning the zeroth element from each split string:

```
df['Part1'] =  df.Col1.str.split(" ").str[0]
```

then to get part 2. Still split on " " but reference elements "1:" to get all other elements. then you can use `str.join()` to put the remaining elements back into one string :

```
df['Part2'] =  df.Col1.str.split(" ").str[1:].str.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas.str.extract(Refular Expression):

```
df['Part1']=df['Col1'].str.extract('^(\w+)')
df['Part2']=df['Col1'].str.extract('\s(.*)$')
```

or combine them together as follows:

```
df[['part1','part2']] = df.Col1.str.extract('^(\w+)\s(.*)$')
```